# Пагинация php\sql

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу сделать пагинацию с помощью запроса mysql, это возможно сделать через limit?
К примеру так

```
$start = $_POST['count'];
$end = $start + 32;
$query ="SELECT `date_modify` FROM `products` WHERE `product_publish` = '1' ORDER BY `date_modify` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$end;
```

Comment: Это через limit, собственно, и делается. Вопрос закрываем?

Comment: Ну так у вас вторая цифра в `LIMIT` это по сколько выводить, а первая - смещение. Что именно у вас не получается? И не забывайте об экранировании переменных. В вашем случае подойдет преобразование типа в `int`.

Comment: @VenZell поменять значения местами надо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш косяк в том, что d mysql LIMIT работает не `LIMIT от, до` а `LIMIT начиная с, сколько`
т.е вам надо

```
$start = $_POST['count'];
$query ="SELECT `date_modify` FROM `products` WHERE `product_publish` = '1' ORDER BY `date_modify` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", 32;";
```